# Importing tables from LaTeX to word and/or PDF

Tags: tables, export, latex-to-word

I am very very new to the MacTex package platform. I have a sets of tables generated in stata and saved in LaTeX format. Can someone please help me with how I can export these tex tables to Microsoft word or pdf for papers and presentations?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! If you have LaTeX code, than ust compile it with pdfLaTeX, for example. Result should be pdf document.

Comment: If you're exporting to LaTeX from Stata, it's assuming you're using LaTeX to write your documents. So if you're not using LaTeX to write documents with, it's likely that Stata can also export tables in a format that Word can understand. It's certainly not the best route to try to convert the LaTeX output of Stata into Word.

Comment: If you're new to LaTeX, you may want to start here: https://www.learnlatex.org/

Comment: How complex are the tables? [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) handles simple tabular environments reasonably well converting from LaTeX to .docx.